# How do I mark a variable private across imports in Gnu Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Gnu make provides `private` variables for specific rules.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suppressing-Inheritance.html

How do I mark a variable private across an import, so that it is only defined in its `file.mk` context, but not in the main `makefile`:

```
# makefile
include file.mk
foo=biz  # this is the value in main make

# file.mk
foo=bar  # make this private; this is the value in file.mk recipes
```

Comment: There is no `import` directive in GNU make. You're probably thinking
of [`include`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include). That is just a pre-processing directive, like C/C++ `#include`. The `include`-ed makefile is interpolated into the reading of the including makefile replacing the directive. There are no namespace implications.

Comment: The only scoping available in GNU Make is scoping per target (and for a target's prerequisites).  There is no such thing as scoping per file.  You will have to use naming conventions or similar to achieve your goals.

Comment: @MikeKinghan It's include in my file. transcription error.

Comment: @MadScientist I think I'll be able to do it w/in those parameters by scoping the included files correctly.  The actual use case is toggling the use of 'sudo' whether I am local or in a dockerfile.

Comment: @Chris If there are errors in your question please edit it and fix the errors.